# Trend in proportion over time for categorical data

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, repeated-measures, proportion

I have some environmental data collected over 4 different years. I'd like to analyses the change in the proportion of responses of good/very good condition over time in r.

Just comparing either good/very good vs. fair/poor over the four years.

|  | 2010 | 2013 | 2017 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Very good | 37 | 34 | 30 | 31 |
| Good | 42 | 41 | 43 | 40 |
| Fair | 41 | 44 | 50 | 45 |
| Poor | 25 | 26 | 22 | 29 |

- Each plot was assessed in each assessment year (repeated measures?)
- Each plot was given a condition score of very good, good, fair or poor (categorical variable?)
- A fifth category "Unknown" was included but I've excluded any plot that was "unknown"

I considered using a Friedman Test but am hesitant to assign a numeric order to my categories (i.e. is "Very good" twice as good as "Good"? Are the categories equally distanced?). Now I'm stumped at how to analyse this dataset.